# E-Social. Assinatura do evento inválida

Tags: api

olá,
estou tendo problemas na consulta de eventos com o protocolo, retorna no xml o erro (405 - Assinatura Inválida), ocorrência (1 - 142 - Assinatura do evento inválida. Ações Sugeridas: Verificar se houve alteração do evento após a assinatura. Verificar a validade da assinatura.)

segue assinatura enviada...

```html
<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
              <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>h2IWj/yBmVC1XM7qrc31hLPXDmECI45abGgzTbCpfb8=</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
              </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
```

Alguém teve esse problema?

Answer (score 3):

Consegui resolver o problema.

Na versão 2.3 dos layouts estava sendo obrigatório informar os Namespaces do Evento.

```html
<eSocial  xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_04_01"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1111111110000002017121316041098000">
```

Como o erro não é sugestivo achei que pudesse ser a ordem em que eu estava fazendo assinatura dentro do lote ou fora do lote.

Mas o problema estava simplesmente em remover esses Namespaces e deixar somente o namespace de identificação do evento:

```html
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_04_01">
```

A ordem que eu fiz de assinatura foi:

1- Montar evento;
2- Validar evento;
3- Assinar evento;
4- Insiro evento no lote;
5- Envio

Depois de assinado, o evento não pode sofrer nenhum tipo de modificação.
Irei enviar logo abaixo o exemplo do lote assinado.
Assim você poderá comparar a estrutura.

Irei remover apenas os detalhes do certificado e da assinatura por motivos de segurança.
Segue lote completo e assinado, este foi enviado e retornou sucesso.

```html
<eSocial xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">
  <envioLoteEventos grupo="1">
    <ideEmpregador>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>12345678</nrInsc>
    </ideEmpregador>
    <ideTransmissor>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>87654321</nrInsc>
    </ideTransmissor>
    <eventos>
      <evento Id="ID1234567800000002017121415120771000">
        <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtInfoEmpregador/v02_04_01">
          <evtInfoEmpregador Id="ID1123456780000002017121415120771000">
            <ideEvento>
              <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
              <procEmi>1</procEmi>
              <verProc>SDA.ABM 1.0</verProc>
            </ideEvento>
            <ideEmpregador>
              <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
              <nrInsc>12345678</nrInsc>
            </ideEmpregador>
            <infoEmpregador>
              <inclusao>
                <idePeriodo>
                  <iniValid>2017-12</iniValid>
                </idePeriodo>
                <infoCadastro>
                  <nmRazao>Razao da Empresa</nmRazao>
                  <classTrib>99</classTrib>
                  <natJurid>3999</natJurid>
                  <indCoop>0</indCoop>
                  <indConstr>0</indConstr>
                  <indDesFolha>1</indDesFolha>
                  <indOptRegEletron>1</indOptRegEletron>
                  <indEntEd>N</indEntEd>
                  <indEtt>N</indEtt>
                  <contato>
                    <nmCtt>James Bond</nmCtt>
                    <cpfCtt>12345678910</cpfCtt>
                    <foneCel>1234707070</foneCel>
                    <email>james.bond@missao007.com</email>
                  </contato>
                  <softwareHouse>
                    <cnpjSoftHouse>123456789</cnpjSoftHouse>
                    <nmRazao>Minha SoftwareHouse</nmRazao>
                    <nmCont>Cia</nmCont>
                    <telefone>1931117070</telefone>
                    <email>cia.secreto@PFB.com</email>
                  </softwareHouse>
                  <infoComplementares>
                    <situacaoPJ>
                      <indSitPJ>0</indSitPJ>
                    </situacaoPJ>
                  </infoComplementares>
                </infoCadastro>
              </inclusao>
            </infoEmpregador>
          </evtInfoEmpregador>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
              <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>............................................</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>...........................................</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>..................................</X509Certificate>
              </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
        </eSocial>
      </evento>
    </eventos>
  </envioLoteEventos>
</eSocial>
```

Estou desenvolvendo utilizando a ferramenta .Net e a linguagem C#
Se eu puder ajudar em mais alguma coisa.

Espero ter ajudado,

**Jean Guilherme**

Answer (score 1):

O Jean já listou a maioria dos problemas que normalmente causam esse erro de assinatura inválida, mas, como é um problema bem comum, vou replicar aqui a resposta que dei em outros posts, que adiciona alguns pontos e dá um exemplo de código em C#.

Algumas dicas básicas que devem ser seguidas para realizar a assinatura com sucesso:

- Você deve usar somente o XML do evento para gerar a assinatura, e depois o XML do evento assinado é embutido no XML do lote. O XML do lote nunca deve ser assinado, somente os eventos, individualmente, são assinados.
- A tag raiz do evento, *eSocial*, não deve conter os elementos **xmlns:xsi** e **xmlns:xsd**, que normalmente são adicionados automaticamente pelo serializador.
- Depois de assinado, o XML do evento não deve sofrer **nenhuma** alteração, porque senão a assinatura se torna inválida. Eu já vi pessoas que alteravam coisas manualmente no XML depois de assinado, e já aconteceu comigo do XML do evento ser gravado em disco usando um encoding e a gravação do XML de lote, com o evento assinado embutido, usar outro enconding, o que também invalidava a assinatura.

Eu fiz uma página há um tempo atrás com algumas dicas sobre como assinar um XML de evento do eSocial:

> http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/AssinaturaXml.htm

Mas, resumindo, o código que estou usando para o eSocial é o seguinte:

```cs
  //
  // SignedXml.CheckSignature Method (X509Certificate2, Boolean) -> Examples [SHA1]
  // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148731(v=vs.110).aspx
  //
  // Using SHA256 with the SignedXml Class
  // https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/winsdk/2015/11/14/using-sha256-with-the-signedxml-class/
  //
  private static void SignXmlDoc(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 certificate)
  {
     //
     // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#Crypto462
     //
     // SignedXml support for SHA-2 hashing The .NET Framework 4.6.2 adds support
     // to the SignedXml class for RSA-SHA256, RSA-SHA384, and RSA-SHA512 PKCS#1
     // signature methods, and SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512 reference digest algorithms.
     //
     // Any programs that have registered a custom SignatureDescription handler into CryptoConfig
     // to add support for these algorithms will continue to function as they did in the past, but
     // since there are now platform defaults, the CryptoConfig registration is no longer necessary.
     //
     //// First of all, we need to register a SignatureDescription class that defines the DigestAlgorithm as SHA256.
     //// You have to reference the System.Deployment assembly in your project.
     //CryptoConfig.AddAlgorithm(
     //   typeof(System.Deployment.Internal.CodeSigning.RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription),
     //   "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
     // RSAPKCS1SHA256SignatureDescription -> Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.5

     SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);

     // Add the key to the SignedXml document. 
     signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();   // Disponível desde .NET Framework 4.6
     //signedXml.SigningKey = GetRSAPrivateKey(certificate);

     //
     // https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#Crypto462
     //
     // SignedXml support for SHA-2 hashing The .NET Framework 4.6.2 adds support
     // to the SignedXml class for RSA-SHA256, RSA-SHA384, and RSA-SHA512 PKCS#1
     // signature methods, and SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512 reference digest algorithms.
     signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigRSASHA256Url; //"http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"

     // Create a reference to be signed. Pass "" to specify that
     // all of the current XML document should be signed.
     Reference reference = new Reference(string.Empty);

     reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
     reference.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
     reference.DigestMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA256Url; //""http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"

     // Add the reference to the SignedXml object.
     signedXml.AddReference(reference);

     signedXml.KeyInfo = new KeyInfo();
     // Load the certificate into a KeyInfoX509Data object
     // and add it to the KeyInfo object.
     signedXml.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate));

     // Compute the signature.
     signedXml.ComputeSignature();

     // Get the XML representation of the signature and save
     // it to an XmlElement object.
     XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

     // Append the element to the XML document.
     xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

     if (xmlDoc.FirstChild is XmlDeclaration)
        xmlDoc.RemoveChild(xmlDoc.FirstChild);
  }
```

Se você tiver que assinar também os eventos do EFD-Reinf a única diferença é que lá o elemento Reference.URI deve conter o ID do evento, com o caractere **#** na frente, ao passo que no eSocial esse elemento deve estar vazio. Então para o EFD-Reinf a linha que cria o objeto *reference*, nessa função que mostrei, deve ser alterada para:

```cs
     Reference reference = new Reference("#" + idEvento);
```

Eu tenho uma página com alguns exemplos de XML do eSocial que, embora estejam desatualizados (todos os exemplos da página estão no leiaute v2.2.02, e o atual é a v2.4.01), são interessantes para visualizar bem o que deve ser assinado (somente o XML do evento) e o que não deve ser assinado (o XML do lote):

> http://suporte.quarta.com.br/eSocial/ExemplosEventosXml.htm