# eSocial: Assinatura Inválida .NET Framework

Tags: c#, .net, web-service, api

### Assinatura Inválida

Boa tarde, estou com um problema na transmissão das informações para os webservices do **eSocial**.
O processo que eu faço é o seguinte: os XMLs dos eventos são gerados no servidor, devolvidos para uma aplicação que roda na máquina do cliente e é responsável por assinar os eventos e realizar a transmissão ao eSocial.
A transmissão do lote é feita e recebida com sucesso, porém ao consultar as informações pelo webservice de consulta ( pelo recibo de entrega devolvido no envio ) é retornado um erro de código **142** e descrição **Assinatura do evento inválida. Ações Sugeridas: Verificar se houve alteração do evento após a assinatura. Verificar a validade da assinatura.**

Vou colocar abaixo o arquivo enviado e o método responsável por assinar.
(Os dados do certificados foram omitidos)

```
<eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/lote/eventos/envio/v1_1_1">
  <envioLoteEventos grupo="2">
    <ideEmpregador>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>95784204000177</nrInsc>
    </ideEmpregador>
    <ideTransmissor>
      <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
      <nrInsc>05964161000119</nrInsc>
    </ideTransmissor>
    <eventos>
      <evento Id="ID1957842040001772018121314262900000">
        <eSocial xmlns="http://www.esocial.gov.br/schema/evt/evtToxic/v02_05_00">
          <evtToxic Id="ID1957842040001772018120609352600000">
            <ideEvento>
              <indRetif>0</indRetif>
              <tpAmb>2</tpAmb>
              <procEmi>1</procEmi>
              <verProc>01.00.00</verProc>
            </ideEvento>
            <ideEmpregador>
              <tpInsc>1</tpInsc>
              <nrInsc>95784204000177</nrInsc>
            </ideEmpregador>
            <ideVinculo>
              <cpfTrab>56641686094</cpfTrab>
              <nisTrab>12025177234</nisTrab>
              <matricula>621</matricula>
            </ideVinculo>
            <toxicologico>
              <dtExame>2018-12-06</dtExame>
              <indRecusa>S</indRecusa>
            </toxicologico>
          </evtToxic>
          <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <SignedInfo>
              <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
              <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" />
              <Reference URI="">
                <Transforms>
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
                  <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
                </Transforms>
                <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" />
                <DigestValue>...</DigestValue>
              </Reference>
            </SignedInfo>
            <SignatureValue>...</SignatureValue>
            <KeyInfo>
              <X509Data>
                <X509Certificate>...</X509Certificate>
              </X509Data>
            </KeyInfo>
          </Signature>
        </eSocial>
      </evento>
    </eventos>
  </envioLoteEventos>
</eSocial>
```

Aqui o código responsável pela criação do lote e a seguir da assinatura do evento.

```
var cl = new WSEsocial.Envio.ServicoEnviarLoteEventosClient();

cl.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(cert.SubjectName.Name, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreLocation.CurrentUser, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.StoreName.My);

XmlElement _getXmlElement(string xml)
{
  var d = new XmlDocument();
  d.LoadXml(_serviceSign.Sign(cert, xml).OuterXml);
  return d.DocumentElement;
}

var lote = new eSocial()
{
  envioLoteEventos = new eSocialEnvioLoteEventos()
  {
    grupo = (sbyte)model.GrupoEvento,
    ideEmpregador = new TIdeEmpregador()
    {
      nrInsc = model.UnidadeInsc,
      tpInsc = (sbyte)model.TipoInsc
    },
    ideTransmissor = new TIdeTransmissor()
    {
      nrInsc = cnpj,
      tpInsc = (sbyte)1
    },
    eventos = new eSocialEnvioLoteEventosEventos()
    {
      evento = model.Eventos.Select(x => new TArquivoEsocial
      {
        Id = x.Id,
        Any = _getXmlElement(x.XmlString)
      }).ToList()
    }
  }
};

public XmlDocument Sign(System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2 cert, string xmlString)
    {
      var doc = new XmlDocument();
      doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
      doc.LoadXml(xmlString);

      Reference referenc = new Reference
      {
        Uri = string.Empty,
        DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256",
      };
      referenc.AddTransform(new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform());
      referenc.AddTransform(new XmlDsigC14NTransform());
      referenc.DigestMethod = XmlSignatureExtensions.SHA256DIGEST;

      var kInfo = new KeyInfo();
      kInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoX509Data(cert));


      var privKey   = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
      var enhCsp    = new RSACryptoServiceProvider().CspKeyContainerInfo;

      var cspparams = new CspParameters(enhCsp.ProviderType, enhCsp.ProviderName, privKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName);
      privKey       = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspparams);

      var signDoc = new SignedXml(doc)
      {
        KeyInfo = kInfo,
        SigningKey = privKey
      };
      signDoc.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";
      signDoc.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigC14NTransformUrl;
      signDoc.AddReference(referenc);


      signDoc.ComputeSignature();

      doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(signDoc.GetXml(), true));

      return doc;
    }
```

Agradeço muito se alguém conseguir me dar uma luz sobre.
**Obrigado**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu chuto que o problema deve estar na forma como você está obtendo a chave privada do certificado, para assinar o XML. Veja que você está pegando as propriedades `ProviderType` e `ProviderName` do objeto `RSACryptoServiceProvider` recém-criado, e não da chave privada do certificado:

```
var privKey   = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey;
var enhCsp    = new RSACryptoServiceProvider().CspKeyContainerInfo;

var cspparams = new CspParameters(enhCsp.ProviderType,
                                  enhCsp.ProviderName,
                                  privKey.CspKeyContainerInfo.KeyContainerName);
privKey       = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspparams);
```

Esse pode até não ser o seu problema atual, mas pode ser um problema no futuro, porque quando você instancia um novo objeto da classe `RSACryptoServiceProvider`, a chave padrão é usada ([documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.-ctor#System_Security_Cryptography_RSACryptoServiceProvider__ctor)), e a chave padrão pode não ser a chave que você quer usar para a assinatura.

Veja essa minha outra resposta no Stack Overflow sobre o assunto:

> [E-Social. Assinatura do evento inválida - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/277470/86952)

Lá há um exemplo de rotina usada para assinar o XML e também algumas dicas de motivos que podem causar esse erro de assinatura inválida.

Veja também essa outra resposta, mais recente, que é sobre EFD-Reinf, mas, é muito similar ao eSocial (a diferença é que no EFD-Reinf o atributo `reference.Uri` deve ter conteúdo e no eSocial deve ser vazio):

> [EFD-Reinf: Erro Assinatura - Um Contexto XmlDocument é necessário para transformações envelopadas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/349264/86952)

Outra coisa, o evento **S-2221** ("Exame Toxicológico do Motorista Profissional") que você está tentando enviar no exemplo, faz parte dos eventos de **Saúde e Segurança do Trabalhador – SST**, que só passarão a ser enviados a partir de julho/2019 para as empresas do Grupo 1 ([cronograma](http://portal.esocial.gov.br/noticias/publicado-novo-cronograma-do-esocial)), e esse evento especificamente foi incluído na versão 2.5 dos leiautes do eSocial, que foi implantada ontem no Ambiente de Produção Restrita, mas só será implantada no dia 21/01/2019 no Ambiente de Produção ([notícia](http://portal.esocial.gov.br/noticias/comite-gestor-aprova-a-versao-2-5-do-leiaute-do-esocial)).

Se você está começando agora no eSocial, o melhor é sempre pegar o evento **S-1000** ("Informações do Empregador/Contribuinte/Órgão Público") primeiro, que é o início de tudo.

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno, estou ciente desta questão do SST, pelo fato de nosso software ser responsável apenas por estes eventos.

Comment: Vou verificar os dois link que encaminhou, muito obrigado

Comment: Entendi @VicenzoMartinelli. Mas de qualquer forma comece testando com um S-1000, porque eu creio que o S-2221 não esteja nem disponível para testar ainda. Depois me diga se conseguiu resolver o erro de assinatura.

Comment: Já efetuei o teste Pedro, realmente o problema estava na forma que estava pegando as informações da chave privada, mudei um pouco o código e funcionou ok.

Comment: Que bom @VicenzoMartinelli! Se puder depois marca a resposta como aceita, então! ;-)  Veja: [Alguém me respondeu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) e [Por que votar?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 0):

Esse problema estava ocorrendo comigo na versão anterior ao **.NET 4.6.2**!

Estranhamente, para o certificado A1 funciona perfeitamente.
Mas para o certificado A3, o mesmo código dá erro na assinatura.

Seguindo o código do [Pedro Gaspar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/86952/pedro-gaspar) nesse post, funcionou corretamente:

> [E-Social. Assinatura do evento inválida - Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/242447/e-social-assinatura-do-evento-inv%C3%A1lida/277470#277470)